# Как с помощью регулярного выражения убрать двойные кавычки, которые находятся вокруг символов?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка `let str = '"a", "!", """, "!", "c"'`
Как с помощью регулярного выражения убрать двойные кавычки, которые находятся вокруг символов. Особенность состоит в том, что это не должно касаться кавычек в кавычках. Вот результат, который должен получиться на примере переменной str - `str = 'a, !, ", !, c'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"(.+?)" меняй на $1
```

https://regex101.com/r/KTL94Q/1

Или без замены, а просто поиском

```
(?<=")(?:(?!(",))[^,])+(?=")
```

https://regex101.com/r/KTL94Q/2